# SQLite: Can I have a where statement inside another where statement?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am writing SQL queries in Ruby on Rails, using Arel, and I will execute these statements in SQLite data base.

Because my queries are composed by other complicated statements, I thought that I can include a where statement inside another where statement.

for example:

```
SELECT * FROM "patients" INNER JOIN "encounters" INNER JOIN "conditions" WHERE "patients"."patient_characteristic_birthdate" <= '1997-06-30 07:25:50 UTC' AND "encounters"."length_of_stay" <= 120 AND "encounters"."encounter" = 'Inpatient Encounter' AND (SELECT * FROM "patients" INNER JOIN "conditions" WHERE ("conditions"."diagnosis" = 'cancer' OR "conditions"."diagnosis" = 'obesity')))
```

For this statement, I have the following error:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression:

For example my data model can be:

```
Patients: encounter_id,ssn, birth_date, gender, race
Conditions: encounter_id,diagnosis, primary_problem
Encounters: patient_id, arrival, departure, lenght_of_stay, encounter
```

data can be:

```
Patients: encounter_id,12345, 12/6/1974, male, latino
Conditions: encounter_id,Obesity, blood presure
Encounter: patient_id,date_start, date_end, 10 days, Encounter inpatient
```

The problem is that I am receiving the queries in a tree structure, so I have to structure a nested statement. But maybe there is also another easier way?

Even I am included the id fields for the joins I am doing, the error is the same.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression
```

It is like I can not include inside a where statement another where statement

Comment: Post up your table structures with sample data

Comment: There is no fields that link each table together?

Comment: there are linked through id, yes I did not included it this

Comment: In your first SQL query, you should use UNION to join the results of the two queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from patients p,encounters AS e, CONDITIONS AS C where p.birth_date <='1997-06-30' AND e.lenght_of_stay<'119' and e.encounter='Inpatient Encounter' and c.diagnosis='cancer' OR c.diagnosis='obesity'
```

Try out if this gives the desired output.
The assumed table structures are :-

desc encounters

```
Name           Null Type         
-------------- ---- ------------ 
PATIENT_ID          VARCHAR2(50) 
ARRIVAL             VARCHAR2(50) 
DEPARTURE           VARCHAR2(50) 
LENGHT_OF_STAY      VARCHAR2(50) 
ENCOUNTER           VARCHAR2(50)
```

desc patients

```
Name         Null Type         
------------ ---- ------------ 
ENCOUNTER_ID      VARCHAR2(50) 
SSN               VARCHAR2(50) 
BIRTH_DATE        VARCHAR2(50) 
GENDER            VARCHAR2(50) 
RACE              VARCHAR2(50)
```

desc CONDITIONS

```
Name            Null Type         
--------------- ---- ------------ 
ENCOUNTER_ID         VARCHAR2(50) 
DIAGNOSIS            VARCHAR2(50) 
PRIMARY_PROBLEM      VARCHAR2(50)
```

The issue in your original query structure is not in your 'where' clause. I feel it is a case of misplaced select statement. Because your query would translate to something like :-

`..AND "encounters"."encounter" = 'Inpatient Encounter' and (--return entire table structure using select *! )` which cannot be analyzed using 'where'. Where requires a filter like parameter=value.

I am skeptical about Using UNION, since to use union,we require same number of expressions in both selects.

You could use a 'where' inside another 'where' as follows (sample):

```
select * from patients where ENCOUNTER_ID='1' and BIRTH_DATE IN (select BIRTH_DATE from patients where birth_date <'2001-07-12');
```